# How to make data tidy at in R for scraping data

Tags: r

So I am trying is to scraping data from [WHO Coronavirus (COVID-19) Dashboard](https://covid19.who.int/table)

I am using R code is

```
library(tidyverse)
whole_word <-'https://covid19.who.int/table'
page_title <- read_html(whole_word)
page_title %>%
  html_nodes(".td") %>%
  html_text()
SLS_df <- tibble(Country =page_title %>%
  html_nodes('.td') %>%
  html_text()) # build the Title variable using the code we used above
SLS_df
tibble <-SLS_df[c(17:160),1]
tibble
```

but what I got is really strange. It shows my tibble has 144*1 and what I want is the same as the webpage. Data set nicely. So what can I do for fixing the problem?

Comment: This is a dynamic page and rvest will have a difficult time handling it.  If you go this page: https://covid19.who.int/data one can download the data directly as a CSV file.  I suggest going this route.

Comment: my work is scraping this web and can not change. i know its hard....

Comment: Then you will need to have a Rselenium solution.  Good luck